# How to NOT round a value using kable

Tags: r, rounding, kable

I am trying to make an ANOVA table for some data collection. Here is the r code:

````
```{r 2e anova}
bigaov = anova(bigmod) 
bigaov[2:4] = round(bigaov[2:4], 2)
options(knitr.kable.NA = '-')
kable(bigaov, col.names = c("Df", "Sum Sq", "Mean Sq", "F-Value", "P- 
Value"),
caption = '\\label{tab:bigaov} The ANOVA table for two-way complete model.')
```
````

The output is displayed below:

[image]

(Please ignore the misleading caption, that is not my concern) My question here is the 0 in the "P-Value" column. `kable` will usually put 0 here, because in this example, p = 2.3 x 10^{-36}; it is 0 when rounded, but I want to enter the exact value in the table. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you might have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325464/how-to-control-knitr-kable-scientific-notation)

Comment: You could use the `format` or `sprintf` functions to output the p-value as a string with specified formatting. For example, you could do something like `bigaov[["Pr(>F)"]] = sprintf("%1.3f", bigaov[["Pr(>F)"]])`. This particular code will give you the p-value to 3 decimal places. See `?sprintf` for additional info on formatting options.

Comment: `format` works perfectly for what I want, thank you!